# Reference an e-commerce order to cookie consent via UTM

Tags: woocommerce, google-analytics, utm-tracking

Is it possible to reference an e-commerce order in WooCommerce with info about if cookie consent was given from the customer who made the order?

**My idea is the following:**

Let's say a user comes from an Ad, so the URL already contains UTM parameters.
The user then sees the cookie banner and clicks on "accept".
The "accept" button **appends** another custom UTM parameter (e.g &consent=1) and opts-in

There are a few plugins that make it possible to see the UTM data for a specific order (e.g "handl utm grabber"). I was wondering if this way I could get insights for a specific order if the customer gave cookie consent or not.

Also, would appending the custom UTM parameter cause any problems (e.g double counting) in Google Analytics in this scenario?

Comment: In case of user press 'no' in cookie consent banner data will not be collected to GA, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. 
Btw, I already compared the purchases in GA against all orders in WooCommerce, and the gap was huge. So I was thinking about this approach as an additional solution to get more insights. My assumption still is, that simply many of the customers who purchased did not give any consent, but I need to get more clarity or data regarding this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter "consent=1" is not UTM parameter, so it won't start new session.